# JQuery Mobile weird JSON behavior gingerbread phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

We are developing a mobile app in which we have to read and display data from a JSON file. Using the GetJSON function, data is read and displayed on the page. However, when we test the application on a Gingerbread phone, the JSON file doesn't load properly. Everything works well on <strike>Android 4.0+ devices.</strike> (Look at update)

The weird thing is when we return to the page which should have data displayed from the JSON file, it actually does display.

```
function loadWorkshops(){
        $.getJSON("js/file.json",function(json){
            var shoarmaID = parseInt(getURLParameter('id'));
            $("#shoarma1").append('<b>' + json.workshops[shoarmaID].titel + '</b><br>Sector:' + json.workshops[shoarmaID].sector + '<br>Beschrijving:' + json.workshops[shoarmaID].beschrijving);
        });
    }
```

The above code loads the file and appends the filedata in an article with ID "shoarma1".

Why does the data not show without returning to the page after initial load (on gingerbread phones).

**Update** After testing on some other devices we came to the conclusion that it doesnt work on 4.0. Apperently it only work on Jellybean devices.

Comment: Yeh i got the same problem..

Comment: me, too, but it works on 4.0.3 and not on 2.3.3.  @MatthijsL figure out why?